# How to unmarshal nested child elements in java with same tag name?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

In Java I am able to read XML by adding the values into my POJO. But I am not sure how would I able to do the same with sub-child nodes. I provided my POJO example and the XML sub class node.

**XML:**

```
<results>
    <rootNode>
        <node>1336</node>
        <state>CL</state>
        <time>0</time>
        <ip_addresses>
             <ip_address type="DOC">06:56:43.0</ip_address>
             <ip_address type="PE">06:56:43.0</ip_address>
        </ip_addresses>
        <lease_date>2017-01-25</lease_date>
    </rootNode>
</results>
```

**POJO:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "rootNode")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class readingXml
{
    private int id;

    @XmlElement(name = "node")
    private String node;
    @XmlElement(name = "state")
    private String state;

    // How to do the same with sub child-nodes
    @XmlElement(name = "ip_addresses")
    private String ip_addresses;
    // What to do here?

    @XmlElement(name = "lease_date")
    private String lease_date;

    // Getters and setters for all above
```

Comment: Serge answer seems correct can't understand what problem you have

Comment: seen your update, but it is getting confusing are you using Serge's IPAddress  class?

Comment: I think he is just using String list with a wrapper right now

Comment: @serge Yeah probably.

Comment: Im going to delete my updates, and start a new post. Serge did technically answered my original question.

Comment: we are confused to, maybe another xml is arriving, who knows?, the correct solution is serge's solution, you need to start to take a deep breath, check that you have implement as serge's told, debug the incoming xml and the result of your classes

Comment: Yeah it's weird that you cant call to the same code and yet if you paste it in it works, maybe there is something you are overlooking. Can you paste those two different controller cases?

Comment: @serge Here is my new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012604/how-come-modelandview-only-prints-the-first-index-of-an-list I am not sure whats a good title for this PO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put something like this:

```
@XmlElement(name = "ip_addresses")
private IPAddresses ipAddresses;
```

and IPAddresses POJO class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ip_addresses")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IPAddresses implements Serializable {
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name = "ip_address")
    private List<IPAddress> ipAddresses;

    public List<IPAddress> getIpAddresses() {
        return ipAddresses;
    }
    public void setIpAddresses(List<IPAddress> ipAddresses) {
        this.ipAddresses = ipAddresses;
    }
}
```

Where IPAddress is another POJO class that describes the structure of the individual element.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ip_address")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IPAddress implements Serializable {
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlValue
    protected String content;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    protected String type;

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setType(String content) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
To print them do something like this:

```
for (IPAddress ipAddress in custinfo.getIpAddresses().getIpAddresses()) {
    System.out.println("value: " + ipAddress.getContent());
    System.out.println("type: " + ipAddress.getType());
}
```

Comment: I followed your steps. It did not work. When I return the ipAddresses, I receive an weird text like root.project.model[GFG3343]

Comment: You mean when you deserialize? What you mean by return? Can you show full error?

Comment: hmmm.. I can pull  my values from the XML such as NODE, State.. etc It would return 1336, CL. But I can't pull ip_addressses, It is coming in as blank. I implemented your method. But I still don't receive the two IP addresses

Comment: I forgot to add content for the string value. Can you try this? See my updated answer

Comment: I'm still getting a array text as a response. How can I get the values that I setted in the IPAdress POJO into the main pojo where I can just print the values? added your method in my post.

Comment: You just need to loop through the array you get back and you will get IPAddress objects and print the individual values correspondent to the properties inside the IPAddress object. You just can't print the list automatically since you don't have the `toString` method in your IPAddress class

Comment: Check out the new addition I put on my answer

Comment: How would I distinguish the child nodes if they both have the tag ip_address

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134206/discussion-between-mike-chun-and-serge).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the type of "ip_addresses" from String to another POJO class.

E.g.

```
   @XmlElement(name = "ip_addresses")
    private List<Address> ip_addresses;
```

And then define your Address POJO as

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "ip_addresses")
public class Address {

    @XmlElement(type = "DOC")
    protected String ip_address1;

    @XmlElement(type = "PE")
    protected String ip_address2;

    public String getIp_address1() {
        return ip_address1;
    }

    public void setIp_address1(String value) {
        this.ip_address1= value;
    }

    public String getIp_address2() {
        return ip_address2;
    }

    public void setIp_address2(String value) {
        this.ip_address2= value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I get a "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Class" on @XmlElement(type = "PE") and "DOC"

Comment: Define your field order on the main pojo. `@XmlType(name = "readingXml", propOrder = {
    "node",
    "state",
    "ip_addresses"
}`

Comment: I've added that in my main POJO. I also receive "Address cannot be resolved to a type" in my main POJO when I added the code below e.g; into my main POJO.